# PostgreSQL trigger to update field when other field in the same table is updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update

I'm fairly new to SQL triggers and I'm struggling whit this:

I have a table that stores data about properties and their prices:

```
id_property price   area    price_m2
1           1500    60      25
2           3500    85      41
```

The clients could change the `price` of their property often, but the `area` won't. So I want to create a trigger that updates the `price_m2` column when the `price` column is updated.

I've tried something like that or similar variations:

**First create the function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_precio_m2() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
    $$
    BEGIN
        update my_table
        set price_m2 = new.price/old.area
        where (old.id = new.id);

        RETURN new;
    end
    $$
language plpgsql;
```

**Then create the trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_price_m2
    AFTER UPDATE ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (
        old.price IS DISTINCT FROM new.price
        )
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_price_m2();
```

But when I change the `price` I got unexpected results, like the `price_m2` column change for various `id's` when I only want to change the value for one `id` (the one who changed).

**Note**
I know it's an antipattern to store columns whose value depends on the operation between two other columns, but there is a reason for that in this case

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using a recent version of postgres, it would be easier to use a generated column.

Comment: Hey, @Jeremy that's a great feature! Solved my problem. If you want post it as a response and I give you the accepted mark

Comment: Generated column is the best choice. Just to answer your question the problem is in the `where`. You should have wrote `where my_table.id = new.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to follow up on this question so it can be closed, my recommendation in the comments was to use a generated column, which have been available since postgres 12:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

The syntax would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id_property bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  price int,
  area int,
  price_m2 int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (price / area) STORED
);
```